# NameError: name 'x' is not defined Python

Tags: python, list, random, var, nameerror

I'm trying to get around this error but can't find a solution. Actually the code worked perfectly some time but suddendly started to drop the error:

```
"NameError: name 'number_exit' is not defined"
```

And also:

```
"NameError: name 'price_buy' is not defined"
```

The code is generating a list of random numbers

```
import numpy as np

# This function generates a list of numbers under certain rules
def num_var_list():
    global number_list, number_exit, number_target
    number_list = []
    number_target = number_exit
    num_max_robot = (number_target * 20) / 100
    while num_max_robot > 0:
        num_robot = np.random.randint(1,int(num_max_robot))
        if num_robot > number_target:
                number_list.append(number_target)
        else: 
            number_list.append(num_robot)
        number_target = number_target - number_target
    return number_list
        
# This function generates a random number between a certain range
def fun_price_buy():
    global price_buy
    price_buy = np.random.randint(50000,300000)
    return price_buy

# This function generates a random number between a certain range
def fun_mx_buy():
    global number_exit
    number_exit = np.random.randint(50, 150)
    return number_exit

lista_number_list = []
lista_price_buy = []
lista_mx_buy = []

# This loop append each function 50 times to a new list
while len(lista_price_buy) <= 50: 
    lista_number_list.append(num_var_list())
    lista_price_buy.append(fun_price_buy())
    lista_mx_buy.append(fun_mx_buy())
```

Actually, when `Python` doesn't drop the error, the code makes exactly what I want it to do. So I'm not sure how to adjust it to let it work without NameError warnings.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should start to pass arguments to your functions, instead of misusing `global` to try to get variables into scope

Comment: also You have not defined them out of the scope of functions so that global is not gonna work

Comment: `num_var_list` can't work, you never change the value of `num_max_robot ` in the loop, so this is an infinite loops it seems

Comment: @azro not infinite loop. Is even working actually when I define variables using "global" . But then sometimes Python starts dropping the NameErrors and sto working..I would like to know how to define thos values outside of the functions, since the functions generates random values for those variables..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing `global price_buy` that means you use the globally defined `price_buy` to be defined localy in your method but

- neither `price_buy` nor `number_exit` are defined globally (outside a method)
- you don't need global variable

They only to be local, and just better : inlined

```
def fun_price_buy():
    price_buy = np.random.randint(50000,300000)
    return price_buy

# inline, no temporaty variable is needed
def fun_price_buy():
    return np.random.randint(50000,300000)
```

---

Finally, and if you want to get the value from the method in a variable for doing something with it:

```py
import numpy as np

# This function generates a list of numbers under certain rules
def num_var_list(number_exit):
    number_list = []
    number_target = number_exit
    num_max_robot = (number_target * 20) / 100
    while num_max_robot > 0:
        num_robot = np.random.randint(1,int(num_max_robot))
        if num_robot > number_target:
                number_list.append(number_target)
        else: 
            number_list.append(num_robot)
        number_target = number_target - number_target
    return number_list
        
def fun_price_buy():
    return np.random.randint(50000,300000)

def fun_mx_buy():
    return np.random.randint(50, 150)

lista_number_list = []
lista_price_buy = []
lista_mx_buy = []

# This loop append each function 50 times to a new list
while len(lista_price_buy) <= 50: 
    number_exit = fun_mx_buy()
    price_buy = fun_price_buy()
    vr_list = num_var_list(number_exit)
   
    lista_number_list.append(vr_list)
    lista_price_buy.append(price_buy )
    lista_mx_buy.append(number_exit )
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to recall later the variables, so not naming that doesn't suit for my purpose..

Comment: @Foldhy Why use the variable, you store the data in a list ? That's bad use to save a variable in one method, and call thta varaible in another method. Please explain your usecase (preferably in your initialpost)

Comment: Hi @azro The code is intended for a simulation scenario, so yes I need to store data into lists and then create a dictionary and a DataFrame to explore the data. Some functions create a list and others just create a value wich is later stored into a list. So I don't understand yet how to define variables wihout using "global", even because the variables changes their value since random numbers are being generated..

Comment: Yes finally the best solution is the one you pointed out. To call the variables outside of the function providing their function name as the value. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

why do you have so much global ?

```
def num_var_list():
    number_exit=fun_mx_buy()
    number_list = []
    number_target = number_exit
    num_max_robot = (number_target * 20) / 100
    while num_max_robot > 0:
        num_robot = np.random.randint(1, int(num_max_robot))
        if num_robot > number_target:
            number_list.append(number_target)
        else:
            number_list.append(num_robot)
        number_target = number_target - number_target
    return number_list
```

is it works for you?

Comment: Edit: calling the variables function changes the loops..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are defining variables via globals inside a function. You'll want to convert your `price_buy` and `number_exit` to local variables.

or:

```py
# This function generates a random number between a certain range
def fun_price_buy():
    return np.random.randint(50000,300000)

# This function generates a random number between a certain range
def fun_mx_buy():
    return np.random.randint(50, 150)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. But I need the variables to be named to re-call them later..

Comment: Then you name them where you need them when you call the function.

`variable1 = fun_price_buy()`
`variable2 = fun_mx_buy()`

etc.  You can read more about variable scoping here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use global variables (as other answers pointed, not a recommended approach), you will have to give them a value before using them:

```
number_exit = 0
# This function generates a list of numbers under certain rules
def num_var_list():
    global number_list, number_exit, number_target
    number_list = []
```

You can instantiate `number_exit` in the scope of the function as well, but you need to do so before actually using it.

```
# This function generates a list of numbers under certain rules
def num_var_list():
    global number_list, number_exit, number_target
    number_list = []
    number_exit = 0
```

Comment: Hello, doesn't really solve the issue because doing so, later on in the code I get this ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined those global variables. Typing `global whatever` doesn't automatically define a variable called `whatever`. It just tells the interpreter that there's an existing variable called `whatever` in global scope.

For example, the following code produces no errors:

```
blah = 'yada'

def foo(bar):
    global blah
    print(blah, bar)
    
foo('test') # output: yada test
```

Whereas in this example, if the global variable isn't defined beforehand (I commented it out), it gets the same error as you:

```
#blah = 'yada'

def foo(bar):
    global blah
    print(blah, bar)
    
foo('test') # output: NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

So, to stop getting the error, you have to give your global variables some value beforehand, like `None`. Although you could be avoiding globals altogether if you used a class to hold those values you need, like this:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #you'll have to set the numerical values to something that causes num_var_list to not loop infinitely
        self.number_list = None
        self.number_exit = 0
        self.number_target = 0
        self.price_buy = 0

    # This function generates a list of numbers under certain rules
    def num_var_list(self):
        self.number_list = []
        self.number_target = self.number_exit
        num_max_robot = (self.number_target * 20) / 100
        while num_max_robot > 0:
            num_robot = np.random.randint(1,int(num_max_robot))
            if num_robot > self.number_target:
                    self.number_list.append(self.number_target)
            else: 
                self.number_list.append(num_robot)
            self.number_target = self.number_target - self.number_target
        return self.number_list
            
    # This function generates a random number between a certain range
    def fun_price_buy(self):
        self.price_buy = np.random.randint(50000,300000)
        return self.price_buy

    # This function generates a random number between a certain range
    def fun_mx_buy(self):
        self.number_exit = np.random.randint(50, 150)
        return self.number_exit

def main():
    lista_number_list = []
    lista_price_buy = []
    lista_mx_buy = []
    
    my_class_instance = MyClass()

    # This loop append each function 50 times to a new list
    while len(lista_price_buy) <= 50: 
        lista_number_list.append(my_class_instance.num_var_list())
        lista_price_buy.append(my_class_instance.fun_price_buy())
        lista_mx_buy.append(my_class_instance.fun_mx_buy())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for commenting. So you suggest that the other solution is to use a class to define variables? Could you just make the example?

Comment: @Foldhy okay I updated my post with an example of using a class to hold the global variables for your program. It ought to be identical to your program except not using glovals. Although when I ran it to make sure it worked, the program looped infinitely. I think this is because `num_var_list()` was being run before the other two functions, even though it relies on those functions giving a value to `number_exit` and `price_buy`. In your `__init__` you could initialize those variables with their corresponding functions, for instance `self.price_buy = fun_price_buy()`.

Comment: I've gone through your code, thank you very much is way more clear. ?l'll implement it to check it out